# How to get Text Changed Event of Tooltip in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need to  get the text changed event of tooltip. But I cant see any event like this.

How can I get this event or events which enable me to get this event?

Any help will be greately appreciated.

İbrahim

Comment: How is the ToolTip changed?  Via binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually bind the value of your ToolTip to a property of your view model.
However if you really require an event, you would do this:

```
 SomeMethod()
 {
    ...
    var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(
                     ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, typeof (UIElement));

    // we're interested in a TextBox called textBox
    descriptor.AddValueChanged(textBox, TooltipChanged);
    ...

    textBox.ToolTip = "Hello";
}

private void TooltipChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // output's "Hello"
    Debug.WriteLine(textBox.ToolTip);
}
```